# Case Sensitivity and Indices in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I am creating a system where is use e-mail address as unique identifier. There are times I need to look for a user by  the e-mail address. If the user enters the e-mail address in all lower case, but the database has it stored as mixed case, is it a full scan, or will the database still use the index?

This really is a problem because I attempt to validate that the e-mail address is valid when adding the user to the system.

I am using grails with MYSQL on the back end for the database.
I am currently doing this to find the user

```
def c = User.createCriteria()
def currentUser = c.get() { ilike('emailAddress',message.sender.address) }
```

I know I can force the case at the UI, but I would also like to force it at the model level

Thanks, and sorry for the long question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Grails you have a few options to validate the model:

You can [write a setter for the emailAddress](http://colinharrington.net/blog/2009/01/gorm-override-a-setter-on-a-grails-domain/) that converts it to a consistent case:

```
public void setEmailAddress(email){ 
    emailAddress = email
}
```

A more involved but correct answer would be to [create a custom editor](http://blog.openmind.ws/2009/06/25/creating-custom-propertyeditor/) ([PropertySupportEditor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorSupport.html)) that will handle the normalization for you automatically.

You will also would want to write a custom [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) to ensure that Grails' validation fails if the `emailAddress` is not correctly normalized.  If you wanted to make it really elegant you could make the validator into a reusable constrtaint using the [constraints plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/constraints) which could result in something like this:

```
static constraints = {
    emailAddress(normalizedEmail:true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL specifies [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/charset-syntax.html) for every character column, which may be case-sensitive or case-insensitive.

Index is built using whatever collation is specified on the column, so:

1. Alter your table to specify case-insensitive collation on email column (like `ascii-general-ci`, for example).
2. Rebuild your index.
3. Enjoy.

Keep in mind that **all** queries against email will now be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MySQL does not support function based indexes like Postgres and Oracle. ([Source](http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=1075))

A possible workaround in MySQL is to add another column for lower case e-mail addresses, and a trigger that populates it with lower case e-mails on all updates and inserts. Then simply index that column, and use that for your lookups.

With a function based index, you would have been able to do the following:

```
CREATE INDEX 
    ix_users
ON 
    table_users
USING 
    lower(email_address);
```